# Почему функция, которая должна возвращать сортированный по возрастанию список чисел возвращает None?

Tags: python

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы на вход программы подавалась строка, содержащая целые числа, и программа возвращала сортированный по возрастанию список этих чисел. Но программа возвращает None. Из-за чего это происходит?

Вот код:

```py
Lst = input('Введите несколько натуральных чисел:').split()

    
def sort_list(lst):
    for i in lst:
        lst[lst.index(i)] = int(i)
    return lst.sort()


print(sort_list(Lst))
```

Comment: По-моему вы сильно переусложнили код, всё это можно записать всего в одну строку `print(sorted([int(x) for x in input('> ').split()]))`

Answer (score 2):

Потому что метод sort() просто сортирует список "на месте" (мутирует объект и все), он ничего не возвращает.
Если хотите вернуть отсортированный список, то просто напишите так:

```
return sorted(lst)
```

А если же использовать метод sort(), то так:

```
lst.sort()
return lst
```

Comment: Python имеет два вида сортировки: метод сортировки (или "функция-член" ) и функцию сортировки. Метод sort работает над содержимым объекта с именем - считайте его как действие, которое объект берет для переупорядочения. Функция сортировки - это операция над данными, представленными объектом, и возвращает новый объект с тем же содержимым в отсортированном порядке.